# How to treat all directories in a Git directory as normal directories including .git/?

Tags: git

I want to init a directory as a git repo, but it contains a lot of `.git/` directories. Git will treat them as submodules. This is not what I expect.

For example, I want to create a `config.git` repo which contains `config.git/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/.git/` etc..

I still want to keep `.git/` directories in the sub directories. Just store them as what they are.

Some people suggest to rename or remove `.git/` directories. This is not what I want.

I tried `submodule`, `subtree`, `rm -rf cache`, `update-index --assume-unchanged` etc.. commands. I found many online articles. But none of them works as what I expect. I am not sure if I miss anything.

### Addendum

To reply a comment why I want to do this. I just want to make my config directory be a Git project so that I can track all changes and `git push` it to a server.

My environment is something like this:

```
$ ls -al ~/config.git/

......
.screenrc
.ssh/
.vim/
.vimrc
.zshrc
bin/
......
......
```

```
$ cd ~
$ ls -l .vimrc .vim .zshrc

.vimrc -> config.git/.vimrc
.vim -> config.git/.vim/
.zshrc -> config.git/.zshrc
```

But there are many `.git/` directories, such as `config.git/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/.git/`.

When I `git push`, `git clone config.git` etc.., it won't store those sub module files.

I am also open to any better solutions.

Comment: Do you want to let git handle the content of the `.git` folders as if they were normal files? I.e. commit changes to them, being able to undo some of those changes.... That surprises me. Might this be a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: *This is not what I expect.* But that's how Git works. Can you explain the specific goal you have in mind? What you're describing is a desired solution to a problem. But you may be trying to solve the wrong problem entirely.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry that I don't quite get what you mean. I just want git treat they are normal files. commit changes to them are normal files too. As long as `config.git` repo concerns, they are normal files, like normal text files.  I don't know what else I can say to make myself clear. Sorry that I am not a native English speaker. `config.git` repo should only know there is one repo. It should not know there are any submodules. All other files are normal files, like foo.txt.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for your comment. It's just like the example I gave. I want to use git to manage all config files. Some of config directories are git module too, eg: `config.git/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/.git/`. In my system, I have `ln -s config.git/.vim/ ~/.vim`. In the past, I either `tar` (zip) them or simply store them as normal directories without git. But that is not a perfect solution. I can not revert back some config files to previous version. So I want to init the config.git to be a git project now and this problem can not be workaround so far. I don't want to remove `.git/` dirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard because Git forbids it.  A Git repository *is **not allowed** to* contain another Git repository.  Any file whose name contains `.git/` or `/.git` or `/.git/`, in any upper and/or lower case mix (so `.giT/` or `/.GIT/` are included) is forbidden.

This guarantees that it is OK to clone a `.git` repository, such that no evil things will happen due to, e.g., `foo/.git/hooks/post-checkout` existing.

Comment: just curious : how were you able to become a Master in git. A word or two would help others like me too(I understand experience plays a big role, but is it just that?). Even [VonC admires your advanced knowledge level](https://twitter.com/vonc_/status/887206559796912128?lang=en). I literally had this bookmarked in my browser.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick: I've been using Git since about 2007 or 2008, and I have spent some time studying version control systems in general.

Comment: // `some time` studying version control systems// That's a humble and genuine response. Thanks for your words. You have definitely watched version control systems evolve.