# git super repository with double versioning

Tags: git

On my linux system, I want to create a git repository in my `~/Documents/` directory, together with a `cron` job that updates the repository daily, automatically adding and updating text files that match a suitable pattern.

The thing is that the directory contains subdirectories which already contain their own git repositories, and I would like the global git repository just to ignore them (the subrepos, not the subdirs), and version all the files in the subdirectories again.

Is such a setup possible with git?

I've seen git "submodules" mentioned in connection with nested repositories, but I think that's not what I want since I don't want to integrate repositories in subdirectories, but rather ignore them.

Comment: Just add whatever folders you want to ignore to the parent `.gitignore`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I do not want to ignore folders, I want to ignore the fact that they already contain git repositories, and version them again.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand the question... If I understand you correctly, you have a repository which contains folders which themselves house repositories, and you want to  *include* changes to these folders in the parent repository versioning. That's the default behaviour. The fact that the folders already contain *other* repositories is irrelevant, and you don't need to worry about it; changes to the files will reflect a change in both parent repository and child repository by default.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I just did `git init` in the superdirectory and then `git add`ed a directory already containing a git repo. This gave a warning:

warning: adding embedded git repository: infty-lccc
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> infty-lccc
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index ...

Answer (score 3):

> I do not want to ignore folders, I want to ignore the fact that they already contain git repositories, and version them again.

As a practical workaround, I would (in the cron-scheduled daily script)

- find and rename any `.git/` nested repository into `.git.ori`,
- make sure `~/Documents/.gitignore` includes `.git.ori`,
- add everything from `~/Documents`: that will include all the nested Git repositories content, since they are no longer recognized as Git repositories,
- restore all `.git.ori` in `.git/`

Comment: That's an idea, but moving all .git folders twice for each run of the script is a bit worrying. If the script is interrupted before moving everything back, everything is messed up.

Comment: @user313032 " everything is messed up": you could mitigate this by calling the script (again), this time with a `-check` parameter, in order for said script to check if there is any `.git.old/` subfolder remaining, and renaming them.

Answer (score 2):

So basically the answer is no. Nested repositories are not supported except as submodules. If we have this hierarchy:

```
myFolder
.git
    myInnerFolder
    .git
```

...then if `myInnerFolder` is visible to the `.git` of `myFolder` at all, it is seen as a submodule. Your choices are either to ignore `myInnerFolder` so that the higher level Git never even looks inside it, or to accept the fact that a repo inside another repo's working tree is a submodule.

Comment: Thanks! That would make sense. But might you have a link to where that's stated in the documentation? I'm asking since it seems to contradict the comments by obsidian age above if I understand correctly

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the documentation". I'm just telling you some facts about how Git works. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68165971/how-to-treat-all-directories-in-a-git-directory-as-normal-directories-including - in fact we could argue that your question here is merely a duplicate of that.

Comment: That question is about treating .git as a normal directory and indexing it in another repository. I want to ignore .git and index only the files again

Comment: Fair enough, but it is stated very clearly in the answer there that a repository inside another repository's worktree is forbidden. That seemed to be what you were asking me to confirm. How you work around that is up to you, but that is what you must work around.

Comment: in light of the following sentence, my reading of the "forbidden" statement is about explicitly *adding* .git to another repository

Comment: Okay, just trying to help.